# enabling personal hot spot connection deform the view of my iphone application

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, hotspot

When using Personal Hotspot my application's view get distorted. Fields and text, tappable icon and graphic get separated,because of the extra bar beneath the status bar.

Is there any way to adjust the uiviewcontroller according the showing/hiding the hotspot bar, or is there any way to turn off/hide the hotspot notification bar when my application loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status bar essentially doubles in size when someone is connected to the personal hotspot or if there is an active phone call. You have to make sure that your views have the proper autoresizing masks set and that you don't have anything hard coded that expects a certain status bar size.